# Dismissing and Opening a UIPopOver with one UIToolBarItem Button?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, uipopover

I was wondering how I could use 1 button on my ToolBar to open and dismiss my UIPopOver. If I keep tapping the button right now, another PopOver overlaps the previous one. I want ONE button to be able to dismiss and open my PopOver. I tap once, it opens. I tap the button again, it dismisses. Please tell me how. Thanks

Comment: You could use a story board...

Comment: I'm not using storyboard though and a code would've been helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your button tap action event:

```
if (myPopover.popoverVisible)  //self.myPopover if using property
{
    [myPopover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    return;
}

//continue code here to create/present your MyPopover…
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick way to do it is to define a UIPopOverController property in your presenting view controller and use this property to instantiate your popover (and accompanying content view controller).

In your presenting view controller you'll need something like:

```
UIViewController *aViewController = [[UIViewController alloc]init];
self.popOverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:aViewController];
```

Then in your button's action to toggle the popOver it should do something like:

```
    if(self.popOverController.popoverVisible) {
    [self.popOverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    } else { //Display the popover }
```

Hope that help

Comment: its appearing as just a blue popover. Here's my code:       `PopOverView *pickerPopView = [[PopOverView alloc] init];
        UIPopoverController *popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:pickerPopView];
        [self.PopOverController setDelegate:self];
        [self.PopOverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:NO];
        [self.PopOverController setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 260)];
        [self.PopOverController release];` @Jeff