# UIPopOver not displaying content?

Tags: objective-c, uipopovercontroller, uipopover

I'm trying to make my UIPopOver [do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10645529/dismissing-and-opening-a-uipopover-with-one-uitoolbaritem-button) and it's just appearing as a blue UIPopOver without my content showing. This is my code so far in the .m file of my main ViewController:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.PopOverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:viewController];
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

and in my `IBAction` for the button,

```
if (self.PopOverController.popoverVisible) {
    [self.PopOverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
} else {
    PopOverView *pickerPopView = [[PopOverView alloc] init];
    UIPopoverController *popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:pickerPopView];
    [self.PopOverController setDelegate:self];
    [self.PopOverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:NO];
    [self.PopOverController setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 260)];
    [self.PopOverController release];   
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't just add pickerPopView to the UIPopOverController because that is a view not a controller so it is creating problems